# node.js and jQuery: chained command loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

In jQuery and node.js environments, suppose you have the following:

```
var object = new Soda().drink("Coke").drink("Pepsi").drink("7Up");
```

Now let's say I have a list of N drinks and I don't want to hard code this programatically:

```
var object = new Soda().drink("D1").drink("D2").drink("Dn")...
```

What is the programatic approach to this problem if I need this to run sequentially and I **can't** use:

```
var object = new Soda();
for (var in j){
    object.drink(i);
}
```

Comment: Why not modifying the `drink` method so it can accept an array of values?

Answer (score 0):

The line `new Soda().drink("Coke").drink("Pepsi").drink("7Up")` implies that `.drink()` returns a value that by itself is a valid object to call `.drink()` again with (either the original object, or some other object that encapsulates the modified state).

If that is the case, you could:

```
var currentDrinkable = object;
for(var drink in drinks) {
  currentDrinkable = currentDrinkable.drink(drink)
}
```

Comment: Method chaining implies that `drink` returns the instance, there is no need to store the returned value!

Comment: @Vohuman - no it doesn't. it implies it returns a value that by itself is drinkable - just like Promises... `then()` doesn't return the original promise,  but is by itself "thenable".

Comment: That's a different story, since the original code doesn't store the returned value of each `drink` call that's a deductive fallacy.